# How to select index in listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, propertygrid, typeconverter

I display **string array** as **listbox** in **property grid** with **type converter** with code as follow.
How to select index of listbox for initialize first time program loaded? I want SelectedIndex = 0, show first arrData = "one". Any Idea?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string[] arrData = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
    PropertyGrid pGrid = new PropertyGrid();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        FirstClass fClass = new FirstClass(arrData);
        pGrid.SelectedObject = fClass;
        pGrid.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(pGrid);
    }

    public class FirstClass
    {
        public FirstClass(string[] arrData)
        {
            this.DataSource = arrData;
        }

        [Browsable(true)]
        [DefaultValue("one")]
        [TypeConverter(typeof(SecondClass))]
        public string Counter { get; set; }

        [Browsable(false)]
        public string[] DataSource { get; set; }

    }

    public class SecondClass : StringConverter
    {
        public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            FirstClass fClass = (FirstClass)context.Instance;
            if (fClass == null || fClass.DataSource == null)
            {
                return new StandardValuesCollection(new string[0]);
            }
            else
            {
                return new StandardValuesCollection(fClass.DataSource);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right it should be as easy as this code below if you just want to set the index of the selected item in an listbox to 0.

```
ListBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

For further details, please check out the MSDN page.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindex.aspx

Comment: You are right **ListBox.SelectedIndex = 0;** for set the index of ListBox if used ListBox control, but the problem is Counter property used string type, not ListBox.